# DOSKEY to change path and run a command

Tags: dos, doskey

So I have two things I need to do, and it seems DOSKEY is the way to go but i am new to it. 
What I am trying to do is from the C prompt is change drives to D, then go into a folder called run_folder then execute a command that its redirect into a log file.  So it would look like this.

```
C:\Users> D:
D:\> cd run_folder
D:\run_folder> run_command.exe > d:\run_folder\logs_current_date_time.txt
```

I am trying to convert so that all i have to type is run_CA from the C prompt.. 
Any ideas? how i can accomplish this using DOSKEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the three lines of code into a file named `run_CA.cmd`. Then you can type `run_CA` to execute it. No need for DOSKEY.

Comment: `run_CA.bat`, surely? The question is about DOS, not cmd.exe.

Comment: Actually, for most batch files there is no difference if they are called *.bat or *.cmd in Windows if you do not have one of the really old 16 bit Windows versions like Windows 95 or Windows ME.

Comment: Except it's talking about DOSKEY and is tagged "dos", not "cmd" or "cmd.exe".

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so I'm 3 years late to this party but for others who might want to know you can use $T to split commands:

```
doskey run_CA=D: $T cd run_folder $T run_command.exe ^> d:\run_folder\logs_current_date_time.txt
```

Note the caret is required on the command line to escape the redirection, otherwise you'll redirect the output from doskey!